# How to properly handle a PATCH request with Go

Tags: http, go

I have a "Settings" table in my postgresql database with following data :

```
 id | price | duration | start_mn | end_mn | step |                   days_ranges
----+-------+----------+----------+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------
  1 |    50 |       40 |      540 |   1140 |   30 | [{"weekday":3,"ranges":{"from":599, "to":1079}}]
```

I want to handle a patch request that would edit a single field such as duration for instance.

Atm I have an http request with this body : `{duration: 20}`

I'd like to know how to properly patch. On my GO backend these structs are set :

```
type Settings struct {
    Price      int
    Duration   int
    StartMn    int
    EndMn      int
    Step       int
    DaysRanges DaysRanges
}

type DaysRanges []struct {
    WeekDay int
    Ranges  struct {
        From int
        To   int
    }
}
```

Now the function that handles it for now :

```
func PatchSettings(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var settings Settings

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&settings)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

So far I got an object Settings with many fields empty (since only the duration is passed in the body). I can then check each field and if it is not empty process an sql update on that specific field with its value.

But I have a feeling it's quite poor understanding of the PATCH request and the way to deal with it.

I'm looking for a better approach.

Comment: There is no defined way to handle a PATCH. You must invent and implement your own protocol for this, using behavior you define. For example: Does a missing field in your request mean not to modify the value, or does it mean to delete the value?  This is something you must decide. Once you've determined the behavior you desire, we'll be much better able to help you implement that behavior if you're having problems.